# Big UDP multicast messages dropped

Tags: networking, udp, multicast

I have a program that receives udp messages using multicast.
The sender is connected to the same network via ethernet.

I was able to receive relatively small packets ~ 3000 bytes, successfully.
But now that the sender sends larger packets ~ 60000, I no longer receive any data.
I can see the messages in wireshark but I do not receive them in my application.

Do you know what could cause the problem and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: UDP is designed for, and works best with, small datagrams (the recommendations is 576 bytes). If you exceed the MTU, then IP must fragment its packets (bad), and exceeding the IP packet size on reassembly will cause the packets to be dropped. Remember that you _will_ lose packets, and the more you pack into the datagram, the more you will lose when that happens. Real-time protocols (VoIP, video, etc.) use UDP with very small datagrams for that reason.

Comment: So it will always drop big udp messages? If i will be connected to the sender via ethernet? I dont want to reduce the size being sent because it will result in me keeping huge list of the data until all fragments arrive

Comment: That is not at all what I wrote. If you are using ethernet, remember that the ethernet MTU is 1500 bytes, so it will not send a frame payload (IP header and payload, that includes the UDP header and payload) any larger than that. That forces IP to fragment (lots of overhead) on sending, and reassemble (lots more overhead) on reception. IPv4 can only have the entire packet be up to 65,535 bytes, including all the headers involved, and losing any one fragment of a fragmented packet will lose the entire packet.

Comment: You need to design your application-layer protocol to try to prevent sending anything that will exceed the MTU in the path. You can use PMTUD to determine the smallest MTU in the path, and then take into account the overhead of the protocols involved to adjust the amount of data you try to send in a single datagram. As I explained, UDP works bet with small datagrams.

Comment: Ok. So just to see i understand. I need to send for example 60 packets each about size 1000 bytes. and then reassemble them in my application using some header i devised and added to each message. is that correct?

Comment: Something like that, but you really want to use PMTUD to determine a good value to use, and you need to be able to adjust if the PMTU is different. For example, a tunnel  or VPN in the path can shrink the MTU. There is really no magic value, and a good programmer would write the application-layer protocol to determine the PMTU and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I still need to see how to use the PMTUD (im not well versed in networking as you probably saw :))

Comment: Expecting to collect 60 datagrams in your app is not much different from expecting IP to collect 60 (or whatever the number is) fragments for you.  You need to have a plan for what happens when, not if, one or more of those datagrams does not arrive.  Can your app make progress by using only the datagrams that did arrive?  Is it OK to leave gaps and hope that they will be filled in by future transmissions, or do you need to invent a way to get the sender to immediately fill the gap, perhaps by resending the missing datagrams? Should the sender always send multiple copies?  And so on.

Comment: Than you! I'll consider all of this